# ordenamiento de una matriz String por dos columnasjava

Tags: java, matrices, ordenamiento

estoy realizando un programa para gestionar torneos de futbol y el problema con que me tope es que al realizar la tabla de puntuaciones debo ordenarla primero por la puntuación total acumulada en el torneo y luego para definir los lugares si las puntuaciones están empatadas decidir quien va en primer o segundo lugar por los goles a favor y si la puntuación y los goles a favor están empatados definir quien va primero o después por los goles en contra, el problema que tengo es que no se como ordenar la matriz ya que es una matriz de tipo String y para usar un metodo de ordenamiento como burbuja necesito que los datos de puntuación, goles a favor y goles en contra sean int
por el momento solo pongo el codigo donde obtengo los datos y trato de ordenarlos pero no se como convertir las columnas que necesito a int para poder cambiar los datos

````java
 public void orden(){
        //llenado de datos de la matriz que saque de un jtable que carga una tabla de mysql
        String[][] datos = new String[tablaPuntua.getRowCount()][tablaPuntua.getColumnCount()];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tablaPuntua.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < tablaPuntua.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            datos[i][j] = (String) tablaPuntua.getValueAt(i, j);
            }
        }
    //ordenamiento de la matriz
    //n es la entrada de datos
    //g=i y j=h
    for (int g = 0; g < datos.length; g++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < datos[g].length - i - 1; h++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(datos[h][7]) < Integer.parseInt(datos[h + 1][7])) {
                    // Intercambia dos filas de la matriz
                    int[] filaTemp = Integer.parseInt(datos[h]);//error por incompatibilidad de datos
                    datos[h] = datos[h + 1];
                    datos[h + 1] = filaTemp;//error por incompatibilidad de datos

                    // Intercambia dos nombres de equipos
                    String nombreTemp = nombre[j];
                    nombre[j] = nombre[j + 1];
                    nombre[j + 1] = nombreTemp;
                }
            }
        }
    //impresion de matriz
        System.out.println("los datos son");
        for (int k = 0; k < datos.length; k++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int l = 0; l < datos[k].length; l++) {
                System.out.print("dato:"+ datos[k][l]);
            }

        }

    }
```java
````

Comment: probare con el value of por que con parse Int me dio muchos errores

Comment: Una pregunta: tienes los datos en una tabla en MySQL??, si es asi porque no simplemente haces las consultas en MySQL

Comment: si tengo los datos en mysql pero no entiendo a que te refieres, ¿puedo ordenar los datos desde mysql con esas condiciones?

Comment: probé lo que dijiste de hacerlo con mysql y eso fue la solución muchas gracias llevaba cerca de una semana con este problema

Comment: el resumen de la resolucion final es ordenar la tabla desde mysql con el comando
SELECT * FROM nombre de tabla ORDER BY nomrbe de la primer columna DESC, nombre de la segunda DESC, nombre de la tercera DESC;
el DESC es solo para decirle que el orden es de mayor a menor

Comment: Excelente, ahora publica la respuesta para la comunidad XD.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

el resumen de la resolucion final es ordenar la tabla desde mysql con el comando SELECT * FROM nombre de tabla ORDER BY nomrbe de la primer columna DESC, nombre de la segunda DESC, nombre de la tercera DESC; el DESC es solo para decirle que el orden es de mayor a menor